# Java ArrayList contains method

Tags: java

```
@Override
        public boolean contains(Object object) {
            if (object != null) {
                for (E element : a) {
                    if (object.equals(element)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (E element : a) {
                    if (element == null) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I am learning java and I am looking into the source code to find out how certain methods are being written. I would like to ask why is there a need to write

```
else {
        for (E element : a) {
            if (element == null) {
                return true;
            }
         }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Because that is how `null` is treated in that case. And calling `.equals` on `null` would not end well.

Comment: The else part is here in case of testing if the List contains a null Object. In that case, the method will iterate through the List and return true if it finds a null element.

Comment: We cant use `null.equals(element)` because `null` doesn't have any method including `equals`. Such execution will throw `NullPointerException` which we don't want. To compare nulls we use `==`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is.

If `object` is `null`, `object.equals(element)` will throw a `NullPointerException`

So the case where `object` is `null` is handled in a separate loop.

Answer (score 1):

Input argument can be `null` or not `null`.
If it's `null` then we need to iterate through all list elements and return `true` if there is `null` in the array.
And we have to use `==` operator, because `equals` will throw `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @luk2302, my mistake

Comment: ArrayList can have anywhere between zero and Integer.MAX_VALUE `null` references. Not "exactly one".

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Well, I wouldn't say that an ArrayList can have `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements, because such large arrays are normally prohibited by the JVM. But your remark about "exactly one" is correct :D.

Answer (score 0):

In this case your `contains()` method implemented to check if object value is `null` or not, if it is `null` `return true` otherwise `false`. Implementing this method give you a opportunity to check any `object`(passing object as a parameter) value(using `if` condition or any other condition). Later on when you want to check values is there or not if it is have value you can do manipulation on object.

In ArrayList `contains()`:

**The `ArrayList.contains(Object)` method returns `true` if this list contains the specified element.**

```
ArrayList<Integer> listObj = new ArrayList<Integer>();
listObj.add(1);
listObj.add(2);

System.out.println("Contains : "+listObj.contains(1));
```

This method more important check element and do somework if it is `true`. As a example,

```
if(listObj.contains(2)){
  int index=arrlist.indexOf(2);
  listObj.remove(index);
}
```

What is happening here is that the value(object) pass as the parameter is not a null value,

```
public boolean contains(Object object) {
    if (object != null) {
```

then go through the ArrayList element,

```
for (E element : a) {
```

is equal to pass value,

```
if (object.equals(element)) {
```

return true

Otherwise(if object is `null`) go with the else block.

> **Throws**:
>
> `ClassCastException` - if the type of the specified element is incompatible with this list.
>
> `NullPointerException` - if the specified element is null and this list does not permit null elements.
>
> [read more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

---

Let's say object is a `String`:

This `contains()` method also in `String` class. Little bit different scenario but concept is same.

when you wish to check if one `String` contains a specific substring.

```
String word= "Hey there how are you";
if(word.contains("you")){
    System.out.println("I am fine!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to ask why is there a need to write
>
> ```
> else {
> ```
>
> [...]

Because otherwise, the method would always return `false` in the event that the condition of the `if` statement (`object != null`) is not satisfied, but that is inconsistent with the method's contract / documentation.  Many Java `List` implementation can contain the value `null` as an element, and when they do, `contains(null)` must return `true` for them.

That is handled in a separate branch because when `object` is `null`, any attempt to invoke a method on it, such as `equals()` will cause a `NullPointerException` to be thrown.  The approach in the `if` block therefore cannot be applied in that case.

Comment: if object==null and element==null then return true;

Comment: I don't see what you're getting at, @RDR.

Answer (score 0):

List is a collection that allows insertion of null referenced objects into it.

the algorithm meant to tell you that if you have **at least null in the list** and you ask/search a null object later then it will return `true` at the 1st match....

Answer (score 0):

because `.equals()` comparison method cannot be invoked on null and if you would invoke then `null.equals(SOMETHING);` will throw a `NullPointerException`. So here old traditional way comes to the rescue! use `==` comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

Many methods in Collections Framework interfaces are defined in terms of the equals method. For example, the specification for the contains(Object o) method says: "returns true if and only if this collection contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))." This specification should not be construed to imply that invoking Collection.contains with a non-null argument o will cause o.equals(e) to be invoked for any element e. Implementations are free to implement optimizations whereby the equals invocation is avoided, for example, by first comparing the hash codes of the two elements. (The Object.hashCode() specification guarantees that two objects with unequal hash codes cannot be equal.) More generally, implementations of the various Collections Framework interfaces are free to take advantage of the specified behavior of underlying Object methods wherever the implementor deems it appropriate.

Refer:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a need to write `else { ...` because the if condition holds true only if the arg 'object' is not null.